# how to updateOne in Mongodb from Retool?

Tags: mongodb, retool

what's the right syntax in [Retool](http://tryretool.com) to updateOne in mongodb. They have fields called "query" and "update" which don't quite line up with Mongodb.updateOne docs.

[image: retool mongodb query fields]

Answer (score 5):

ah seems $set needs to be in quotes

```
{"$set":{"storageLocation" : "{{packageId.value}}"}}
```